# How do I refresh the list on the homepage view of an entity

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom ribbon button on one of my CRM 2011 entities that will effectively disable that entity.

I then would like to refresh the current view on the homepage of that entity. I would like this triggered by JS.

Currently I'm able to refresh the whole parent window which will put me back at the dashboard and not the home page of that entity.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "home page"? The page where you see multiple records of that entity, or the editor page of a single record? and by disable, you mean deactivate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. Here are two ways you can do it:

```
//refreshes the entire element in the parent window that contains the view
window.parent.opener.location.reload();

//refreshes just the grid control that contains the view (probably what you're looking for)
window.parent.opener.document.getElementById("crmGrid").control.refresh();
```

Comment: I'm using a model popup so opener is unavailable, however I removed that and am using window.parent.document.getElementById("crmGrid") and get Null as the value in the watch window while debugging. I went to verify the name of the grid element but IE's developer tools of course won't allow you to select that area.

Comment: This one worked for me. 
    document.all['crmGrid'].control.refresh();

Comment: Nice, glad to see it worked out. Usually I have to dig in the F12 window in IE, looking at the blue outline until it surrounds the element I want, then dig a little farther to find the actual ID. So it works, but it's tedious.

Comment: agreed. Unfortunetly IE doesn't blue outline the grid or anything in that center area.

Answer (score 3):

### If someone is coming here for Dynamics 365

Do the following for the custom Ribbon Button:

Add the `PrimaryControl` as `CrmParameter` to your JS function

Use the following code to refresh the list:

```
function yourJSFunction(primaryControl) {
    // Do your stuff
    primaryControl.refresh();
}
```

Example for `Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple(...)`:

```
function yourJSFunction(primaryControl) {
    // Create the requests
    // ...

    Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple(requests)
                     .then(function (result) {
                         primaryControl.refresh();
                     });
}
```

Comment: PrimaryControl did not work for me, but SelectedControl did...