# how to refresh dashboard view with js in Mscrm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2015

I've implemented a ribbon button that updates an entity field, based on the entity selected in a dashboard view. After I update the entity field through js, I need to refresh the dashboard view to redisplay the view with the updated field value.

What's the most elegant way to do this? I could execute js to reload the whole page, but would be the worst case scenario. Can you recommend a way to refresh only a specific view on a dashboard to display updated data?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271868/how-do-i-refresh-the-list-on-the-homepage-view-of-an-entity

Comment: thanx @Bactos but that doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Why don't you make an Ajax call to get the updated Dashboard html/ JSON to update the view ?

Comment: @Arkantos can you tell me how to do that ??

Comment: Are you using jQuery ?

Comment: I posted my answer with minimum code, you still need to modify to your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is your main `div` container that holds your entire dashboard html

```
<div id="main-container"> </div>
```

Then if you're already using `jQuery`

```
$('.updateBtn').on('click', function(){
  // update your entity field here
  $.ajax({
    url : 'your-dashboard-url',
    type : 'GET',
    // data : some object in case you want to pass something to server
    dataType : 'html'
  }).done(function(rdata){
        $('#main-container').html(rdata); 
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks , but how can I call this function every 30 seconds and without click event

Comment: you can keep the whole ajax code inside a function say `getDashboardContent` and use that in `setInterval(getDashboardContent, 30000)`

Comment: But are you sure there will always be updated content on server side every 30seconds ? If not, then you're unnecessarily making requests to get same content :)

Comment: That's just jQuery way of selecting all elements with `updateBtn` class

Answer (score 0):

We have a `Custom report` in `IFRAME` at our `dashboard` and we have to apply some `CSS Styles` on that report.

With following lines of code, i was able to get to the `report` and apply styles.

```
var ContentIframe = window.top.document.getElementById('contentIFrame0');
if(ContentIframe!=null)
{
var DashboardIframe=ContentIframe.contentDocument.frames["dashboardFrame"]
if(DashboardIframe!=null)
{
   //DashboardIframe.document.frames["IFRAME_SalesTrend"].document.getElementById("compatibilityNotification").style.display = "none";
```

We have `Activities View` on `dashoboard`, I can get and refresh it like below.

```
 DashboardIframe.document.getElementById("Activities").control.refresh();
}
```

It works and you can also test it in the developer tools Console. It is able to find that element.
[image]

Comment: thank you for answer but that doesn't work :/ <br> Message Error : 'unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference'

Comment: `DashboardIframe.document.getElementById("Activities").control.refresh();`
I can't find `.Control.refresh()` that handle the error and sorry for my english :/

Comment: @abdelazizmaroc that is because you do not have the `Activities` view on your dashboard,

find the name of your `View` that you want to refresh and replace it with `Activities`. Thankx

Comment: I had replace `"Activities"` with the Id of my views but I still had the same error

Comment: @abdelazizmaroc view cannot be Null. As i have attached the screenshot,
you have to use all the code.